# Next.js + SSR not updating the Context API

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-context

We have a simple setup involving a Context API provider wrapping the `_app.tsx` page. The flow we're trying to implement is:

1. On a page we collect some data from an API by using `getServerSideProps`
2. We send the data to the page through the props
3. We update the context from the page (the context provider is wrapping the `_app.tsx` as mentioned above)
4. The context is updated and all the children components can access the data in it

So we have a pretty standard setup that works correctly on the client side. The problem is that the updated context values are not being used to SSR the pages.

### Context API

```js
const ContextValue = createContext();
const ContextUpdate = createContext();

export const ContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [context, setContext] = useState({});
  
  return <ContextValue.Provider value={context}>
    <ContextUpdate.Provider value={setContext}>
      {children}
    </ContextValue.Provider>
  </ContextUpdate.Provider>
}

export const useContextValue = () => {
  const context = useContext(ContextValue);
  return context;
}

export const useContextUpdate = () => {
  const update = useContext(ContextUpdate);
  return update;
}
```

Then we have on `_app.jsx`:

```
...
return <ContextProvider>
  <ContextApiConsumingComponent />
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</Context>
```

And in any page, if we can update the context by using the hook provided above. For example:

```js
export function Index({customData, isSSR}) {
  const update = useContextUpdate();

  if(isSSR) {
    update({customData})
  }
  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  ...

  return {
      props: { customData , isSSR}
  };
};
```

And we can consume the context in our `ContextApiConsumingComponent`:

```js
export function ContextApiConsumingComponent() {
  const context = useContextValue()

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(context?.customData ?? {})}</pre>
}
```

The (very simplified) code above works fine on the client. But during the SSR, if we inspect the HTML sent to the browser by the server, we'll notice that the `<pre></pre>` tags are empty even though the context values are correctly sent to the browser in the `__NEXT_DATA__` script section (they are precisely filled with the data on the browser after the app is loaded).

I've put together a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/julianobrasil/next-js-issue) with a minimum reproduction too.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What value are you returning in `isSSR`? How is that variable defined? You should also not call a state setter function (`setContext` via `update`) directly from render, call it inside a `useEffect`.

Comment: It's defined like this: `const isSSR = !context?.req?.url?.includes('_next/')`. The `update` cannot be called from a `useEffect` because I wanted it to be executed during the server-side rendering. I can add more logic to make this happen only on the server-side though.

Comment: There's a repo with a minimum reproduction here: https://github.com/julianobrasil/next-js-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you have other reasons for using the context to get this data into the api consumer but with nextjs, the `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` of course feeds into the route component, but maybe you've missed the following detail?

> The Component prop is the active page, so whenever you navigate between routes, Component will change to the new page. ***Therefore, any props you send to Component will be received by the page***.

> `pageProps` is an object with the initial props that were preloaded for your page by one of our data fetching methods, otherwise it's an empty object.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

Therefore the `_app.tsx` can act on any props your route components would normally receive from `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`

`types.ts`

```
// or whatever union type you need to indicate that myriad of "custom datas" you might be pushing out of getStaticProps
export type MaybeCustomDataFromGetStaticProps = Map<string, string> | undefined;

export type PagePropsWithCustomData = {
  customData: MaybeCustomDataFromGetStaticProps
  isSSR?: boolean;
}
```

`pages/_app.tsx`

```
import type { PagePropsWithCustomData } from '../types';

const App = ({
  Component,
  pageProps: { customData, isSSR, ...pageProps},
  router,
}: AppProps<PagePropsWithCustomData & Record<string, unknown>>) => {

  return (
    <ContextProvider value={{ isSSR, customData }}>
      <ContextApiConsumingComponent />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ContextProvider>
  )

}
```

`pages/somepage.tsx`

```
import type { NextPage, GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import type { PagePropsWithCustomData } from '../types';
import { magicallyGetCustomData } from '../services/Api';
import { isSSR } from '../core/Routing';

type IndexRouteProps = PagePropsWithCustomData & {
  isSSR?: boolean;
}

const IndexRoute:NextPage<IndexRouteProps> = ({ customData, isSSR }) => {

  // no longer need to do anything with customData, or isSSR here

  return (
    <div>stuff</div>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps:GetServerSideProps<IndexRouteProps> = async (context) => {
  const customData = await magicallyGetCustomData();
  
  return {
      props: { customData , isSSR: isSSR(context) }
  };
};

export default IndexRoute
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't get the context values _durung_ the server side rendering. Which means, in my specific case, that the HTML I send to the browser during the first load is useless from the POV of SEO. I provide more details on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38332

Comment: @julianobrasil I'm currently doing the above and my `magicallyGetCustomData` is called serverside and when i run a SSG build, so i end up with my context filled with the data i expect it to have. So it's strange that you're not. Have you done some breakpoints serverside to confirm that?

Comment: On the github link I left above, there's a link to a repo with the reproduction of the issue: https://github.com/julianobrasil/next-js-issue. I guess the difference is the fact that you're initializing the context with the data instead of updating it later on in the component, right?

Comment: As this question was asked a while ago, I'd have to take a look at the project I was working on at that time to see what exactly I was trying to do. I can see your point and I don't remember exactly why I couldn't do that. Maybe it was because I was learning Next.js... or maybe I had a restriction I currently don't remember anymore :)

Comment: @julianobrasil yeah my first thought was that maybe you did this back when there were other things preventing you from doing it the above way? I also never have a need to send data back up the tree due to using things like redux or mobx anymore since apolloClient and reactQuery replace that concept for me. 
I think it's worth examining it again, since this page comes up in google results for "nextjs ssr context empty" (it will now lol)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, React doesn't wait for asynchronous actions to be performed during the SSR. Whereas setState is an asynchronous operation.

If you want it to be rendered during SSR, you need to provide an `initialValue` for [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook.

```js
export const ContextProvider = ({children, customData}) => {
  const [context, setContext] = useState(customData);
  
  // ...
}
```

Comment: It makes sense... Almost all the frameworks SSR synchronously (Qwik is an exception AFAIK). I'll do some tests, because I don't know the customData in advance to initialize it. Probably going to use a global variable during the SSR.

Comment: You can move the logic of fetching the `customData` to `_app.ts` and then pass `customData` to `ContextProvider` to use it as an initial value. [This document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) may be helpful

Comment: My first attempt was using getInitialProps, but the fact that it's executed once on the server and once on the client didn't help. It's there a pattern to work that around elegantly? I tend to think, again, of a global variable as a solution. I'll check the link you posted, thanks.